# Overwriting document in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to save user location in Firebase by storing the results from getLocation from google location service.

When I use the following code:

```
Lat_Coordinate = location.getLatitude();
Lon_Coordinate = location.getLongitude();

Map<String, Object> user_location = new HashMap<>();
user_location.put( "Lat", Lat_Coordinate );
user_location.put( "Lon", Lon_Coordinate );

db.collection( "Users" ).document( auth.getUid() ).collection( "Location" ).add( user_location );
```

It keeps adding documents to Location collection. However, my goal is always to keep only one document of location which will be the last information.

Is there a way to overwrite the document that already exists instead of adding a new one?

I'm sure there is a way to delete collection then create a new one but I think its too many operations.

Thank you

**SOLUTION:**

What I eventually did was to create again a document with known ID by using auth.getUID and store in it the location. Since the ID is always the same, it overwrites the document:

```
db.collection( "Users" ).document( auth.getUid() ).collection( "Location" ).document(auth.getUid()).set( user_location );
```

Comment: You dont need a nested location then just use an attribute inside or use a document inside the nested location with a fixed document id

Comment: ye thats what I did, just added a document with auth.getUid. Thank you

Comment: @cutiko Do you feel like providing a slightly broader version of the same info as an answer, so we can upvote it (and Ben can accept it)?

Comment: Sure glad to help @puf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is there is a nested collection for the coordinates and every time an operation is performed a new document is created

```
users/uid/location/map
```

The first option is to add the location to the user document as a document attribute

```
db.collection( "Users" ).document( uid ).update("location", map);
```

There could be reasons for adding the location in a nested collection, by example for queries. For so you can do it by defining a static document key:

```
db.collection( "Users" ).document( uid ).collection("location").document("static_key").update("location", map);
```